# Improving the speed of PowerShell commands in Windows 2016

Tags: powershell

Example of a problem:

```
Measure-Command { Get-VMSwitch -SwitchType "External" }
```

Windows 2012 and 2016 have the same hardware and CPU load is ~50%

Windows Server 2016 (3 external Switches)

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 6
Milliseconds      : 377
Ticks             : 63779086
TotalDays         : 7.38183865740741E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00177164127777778
TotalMinutes      : 0.106298476666667
TotalSeconds      : 6.3779086
TotalMilliseconds : 6377.9086
```

Windows Server 2012R2 (3 external Switches)

```
Days : 0
Hours : 0
Minutes : 0
Seconds : 1
Milliseconds : 376
Ticks : 13762494
TotalDays : 1.59288125E-05
TotalHours : 0.0003822915
TotalMinutes : 0.02293749
TotalSeconds : 1.3762494
TotalMilliseconds : 1376.2494
```

Windows 2012R2 with a greater or equal CPU load is 6 times faster.

Windows Server 2016 (9 external Switches)

```
Days : 0
Hours : 0
Minutes : 1
Seconds : 6
Milliseconds : 168
Ticks : 661689307
TotalDays : 0.000765844105324074
TotalHours : 0.0183802585277778
TotalMinutes : 1.10281551166667
TotalSeconds : 66.1689307
TotalMilliseconds : 66168.9307
```

Windows 2016 slower now 48 times! :)

In Windows 2016 Meltdown/Specter fixes are disabled.

Is there any option for improving the performance of powershell commands in Windows 2016?

Thanks.

Comment: How many times did you perform those tests? I would be curious if you ran them all 1000 or even 10000 times. Is it just a matter of loading the module that you are seeing in 2016?

Comment: Tested throughout the summer and not only with this command, it just perfectly show a problem. Certainly not 1000 times, but about 100. And all the time the winner was 2012R2.

Comment: Its a longshot, but perhaps native assemblies arent compiled on the new machine? You might try running `ngen update` and see if it impacts the results.

Comment: ngen update said, - All compilation targets are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found another solution. It's using bottlenecks through WMI. 
The WMI **msvm-ethernetswitchport** class can provide all the VMSwitches elements, where we can already get the same information that Powershel CMD **Get-VMSwitch** provides.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hyperv_v2/msvm-ethernetswitchport and etc.

A simple example:

```
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\virtualization\\v2");

    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Msvm_EthernetSwitchPort");

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                            new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DeviceID : {0}", m["DeviceID"]);
        Console.WriteLine("ElementName : {0}", m["ElementName"]);
    }
```

It's sad that PowerShell in Windows 2016 runs so slowly...

[image: PowerShell vs WMI]

In fact, through WMI there are so many options how to get this data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hyperv_v2/hyper-v-networking-api